# Enable network traffic compression on Redshift over JDBC driver

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-redshift

The network acts as a real bottleneck when queries return large volumes of data (5-200MB).

When connecting to Redshift directly, queries run within a couple of seconds but the results can take a minute or more to download. Connecting via a VPN with compression enabled speeds things up but probably sub-optimally.

Under Postgres, compression seems to be enabled when connecting over SSL.

Is there any way to enable compression over Amazon's Redshift JDBC driver?

Comment: Are you using a generic JDBC driver, or the Amazon Redshift-specific driver? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html

Comment: If you return large volume of data you might be doing something wrong. Better let Redshift do the aggregation for you. You can also use UNLOAD if you have large export of data.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - It's Amazon's own Redshift JDBC driver.

Comment: @Guy Hah well when I said large I was only talking about couple hundred MBs max. Typically just 10's of MBs. UNLOAD looks interesting but that looks more useful for larger amounts